# Can't Install cytoolz on Windows 7

Tags: python, windows, python-3.6

I can't seem to understand what am I missing while I try to install `allennlp`. I already installed `pytorch 1.0` on my environment and I'm working on a `windows 7` machine with `python 3.6` using virtual env. Unfortunately the team of `allennlp` [doesn't support windows users](https://github.com/allenai/allennlp/issues/1178) (It's happening to me at work - Believe me I know it wouldn't happen in Linux)
  When I run  `pip install allennlp` I get the following error:

```
fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
(compiler file 'f:\dd\vctools\compiler\utc\src\p2\main.c', line 246)
 To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program 
 near the locations listed above.
Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++
 Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
  link!objf::ObjectCode::FCreateFromBytesW()+0xaab


build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\cytoolz/dicttoolz.obj : fatal error LNK1000
: Internal error during IMAGE::Pass1

  Version 14.00.23026.0

  ExceptionCode            = C0000005
  ExceptionFlags           = 00000000
  ExceptionAddress         = 0F91A2EB (0F910000) "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mic
  rosoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\msobj140.dll"
  NumberParameters         = 00000002
  ExceptionInformation[ 0] = 00000000
  ExceptionInformation[ 1] = 0009A896

CONTEXT:
  Eax    = 0040E2C4  Esp    = 0040E294
  Ebx    = 00000000  Ebp    = 0040E2A0
  Ecx    = 02F507D0  Esi    = 0009A896
  Edx    = 0F91143C  Edi    = 02F507D0
  Eip    = 0F91A2EB  EFlags = 00010246
  SegCs  = 00000023  SegDs  = 0000002B
  SegSs  = 0000002B  SegEs  = 0000002B
  SegFs  = 00000053  SegGs  = 0000002B
  Dr0    = 00000000  Dr3    = 00000000
  Dr1    = 00000000  Dr6    = 00000000
  Dr2    = 00000000  Dr7    = 00000000
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1000

----------------------------------------
Command "c:\python_env\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, 
tokenize;__f

ile__='C:\\Users\\rg60622\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4qnt9ham\\cytoolz\\ setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\ n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install
--record C:\U sers\rg60622\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-f9nu9may\install-record.txt
--single- version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers c:\python_env\include\sit e\python3.6\cytoolz" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\<soid>\AppData\Local\ Temp\pip-install-4qnt9ham\cytoolz\
```

Any thoughts what should I do?

Comment: "An internal error has occurred in the compiler" - apparently, you broke the compiler, congratulations! :D You can try other compilers, like MinGW's GCC.

Comment: God damn...I thought about this option and I reinstall it maybe I manage to mess up things while doing so,Have no idea how